# R packages that work with biased samples

Tags: r, regression, bias, unbiased-estimator

I'm working with a biased sample of web users.  I'm only able to track responses of users who have navigated my site in a certain way, and I'd like to run an analysis to determine how certain factors (which products they are into, etc) influence how much they buy from my online store.

I've searched around online and found some information on the Heckman Correction, which somehow both won a Nobel Prize and also has extremely little information online, including no R support or youtube videos that I can find.

What are some ways you work with building models that try to correct for biased data?  Are there easy to use software libraries in R?  I have a ton of unlabeled data (products that every user has seen), so it's possible that I could create a naive model for determining probability that a user ends up in my sample if that helps, and I'd be willing to work with more advanced learners like SVM (which I've read can work better for these types of problems) in case linear regressions are a bad choice.

Comment: Have you looked at the package 'sampleSelection' in R? Some papers on it: http://www.jstatsoft.org/v27/i07